# adding a rule to remove leading 0 to an existing regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some numeric-only input in a textbox that I modify with regex like this:

```
if (Text.charAt(0) === '0') {
   Text= Text.substring(1);} }

Text= Text.replace(/(\d{1})?(\d{2})?(\d{2})?(\d{2})?(\d{2})?/, '$1 $2 $3 $4 $5');
```

The desired output should be 1 23 45 67 89. My question is this: how can I add a rule to the regex so that the leading 0 is stripped?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean you want to accomplish this with a regular expression only without using `if` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Text = Text.replace(/^0?(\d{1})?(\d{2})?(\d{2})?(\d{2})?(\d{2})?/, '$1 $2 $3 $4 $5');
```

The single replacement will also remove an optional single leading zero.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/n9V6n/